# Palindrome Partitioning Time Complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity, palindrome, backtracking

I am solving an interview practice question:

*Partition s such that every substring of the partition is a palindrome. Return all possible palindrome partitioning of s.*

My solution is as below, and was accepted.

```
def partition(self, s: str) -> List[List[str]]:
    
    ans = []
    
    def bt(w, curr):
        if not w:
            ans.append(curr)
        else:
            for l in range(1, len(w)+1):
                chunk = w[:l]
                if ''.join(reversed(chunk)) != chunk:
                    continue
                bt(w[l:], curr + [chunk])
    
    bt(s, [])
    return ans
```

The time complexity given in the solutions is O(N * 2^N)

I understand that:

- there are 2^(N-1) possible partitions,
- in the worst case any partition yields palindromes,
- checking for palindrome is linear in the size of the input.

But I am struggling to estimate the amount of work done in the for loop.

Any insight/hints would be helpful. In conjunction with this, I am unable to write a recurrence relation ..

Thank you very much!!

Comment: It looks like you are not considering the recursive call in the function cost.

Comment: @horcrux can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

You have an exponential cost for guessing the solution and a polynomial cost for verifying it. Therefore, the total cost is the product of an exponential function and a polynomial one.

#### Long answer

In the worst case, the `continue` statement will never be reached, so you will have one recursive call for each loop. In this case, if you have a `n`-character-long word, you will have `n` `for` loops, each of which will call up to `n-1` `for` loops, each of which will call up to `n-2` `for` loops... i.e., the cost is `O(n!)`!

However, the factorial cost comes from a very rough estimation for the upper bound and we can be more precise.

In fact, we can notice that the length of the current `chunk` decreases both for each recursion call and for each iteration of the for loop.
For example, if the original string is 4 characters long, the length of the current `chunk` will be:

```
3
├─2
| ├─1
| | ├─0
| | 0
| 1
| ├─0
| 0
2
├─1
| ├─0
| 0
1
├─0
0
```

where the vertical step (`|`) indicates a same-stack-level loop, and the horizontal one (`─`) a recursion call.

It is easy to see that this is `O(2^n)`, indeed the total number of steps is exactly `2^n-1`.

Then, consider that for each iteration you have to reverse the `chunk`, which obviously costs `O(n)`.

Combining the two, you get `O(n*2^n)`.